# Android app crashes for android version 4 or lesser - React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have a react native application in which i have used social login button at first page i.e at login page, when i run my application in android version greater than 4 then it works if android version is less than 4 the app crashes at launch itself, i have tested in OS Version: 4.4.2 , 4.4.4 and 4.3 it crashes in all the above versions. my login button code snippet.

```
<LoginButton
                        publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
                        onLoginFinished={
                        (error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                        alert("login failed");
                        alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                        alert("login is cancelled.");
                        } else {
                         alert("success");
                         }
                         )
                        }
                        }
                        }
/>
```

my version that i am using "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.4.0",
react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.38.0

the crash report from crashlytics is

```
#0. Crashed: main: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2136)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:586)
       at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:64)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:195)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.RCTLoginButton.<init>(RCTLoginButton.java:50)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:56)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:37)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:46)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:218)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:148)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:890)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:863)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:131)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:759)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

--

Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2136)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:586)
       at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:64)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:195)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.RCTLoginButton.<init>(RCTLoginButton.java:50)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:56)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:37)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:46)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:218)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:148)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:890)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:863)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:131)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:759)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2132)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:586)
       at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:64)
       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:195)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.RCTLoginButton.<init>(RCTLoginButton.java:50)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:56)
       at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager.createViewInstance(FBLoginButtonManager.java:37)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:46)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:218)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:148)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:890)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:863)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:131)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:759)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: you should upgrade your gradle file to latest one

Comment: @NiteshMishra i am using gradle version (2.14.1) do i need to upgrade and if i upgrade will it cause any issue with other functionality.

Comment: have you written this new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager) inside your Application class?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum version supported by React Native is Android 4.1 (API 16)

More details here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native#react-native---

Comment: @vinayar app crashes in android OS Version: 4.4.2 (API 19)